# Maximum possible value of an array after swap operation

Tags: arrays, max, dynamic-programming

Given an array of size N (say).
**A1, A2, ... AN**.
Given a predefined list of swap operations:
**(a1, a2), (b1, b2), ... (x1, x2)**.

What will be the maximum sum of the array after the swap operation ?
How it can be done using dynamic programming i.e., recursive formula ?

For Example.,
**Array = {3, 5, 9, 6, 1}**
Given swap operations:
**{ (9,3), (1,2), (8,6) }**

So, we can swap "3" from the array with "9", because (9,3) is a swap operation given.
Similarly, we can swap "1" with "2" because (1,2) is a swap operation given.
Then "6" will be replaced by "8".

So, **new array = {9, 5, 9, 8, 2}**
and **sum = 9+5+9+8+2 = 33** , which is maximum after the swap operation.

So, How it will be solved using dynamic programming ?
Any other approach ?

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried ourself?

Comment: c++, i tried to store the values in an array, but it fails for few cases